Как оценить загруженность сетевого интерфейса?
Я создаю приложение которое сильно загружает сетевой интерфейс. Для контроля за его перегрузкой хотелось бы как то оценивать его загруженность и при пороговых значениях применять меры. Но к сожалению я не знаю как оценить загруженность, вернее даже не знаю на какие параметры нужно смотреть и где их найти.

Вот тут https://habr.com/ru/companies/vk/articles/314168/ очень много всего написано, а вообще /proc/net в помощь

Под загруженностью интерфейса здесь, как я понимаю, имеется в виду отношение мгновенной скорости приёма/передачи к максимальной.
Статистика об использовании интерфейса находится в каталоге /sys/class/net/<interface>/statistics.
Здесь будут интересовать:
rx_bytes - принято за всё время, байт
rx_packets - принято за всё время, пакетов

tx_bytes - отправлено за всё время, байт
tx_packets - отправлено за всё время, пакетов

Приемлемое решение:

Получить информацию о максимальной скорости интерфейса:

/sys/class/net/<interface>/speed для интерфейсов проводных сетей
любым из способов из этого вопроса для беспроводных сетей.


Читать указанные выше файлы через фиксированный промежуток времени (например, каждую секунду), определяя среднюю скорость работы интерфейса за этот промежуток.

Загруженность интерфейса получить, поделив мгновенную скорость на максимальную.



Утилита iftop полностью закрывает мои потребности в мониторинге, можно также рассмотреть atop.

Но какие метрики она отслеживает? Как их получить тоже? Мне же нужно програмнное решение

попробуйте использовать утилиту nethogs

Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.
